# systemd unit "Before=" with timer

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

In my system I have b.service activated by b.timer. I want another service (a.service) that start before b.service. I cant change b.service or b.timer because are not mine. I've putte `Before=b.service` in a.service but the timer start b.service without starting a.service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark `a.service` as `RequiredBy` `b.service`.

Make `a.service` look like:

```
[Unit]
Before=b.service

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=...

[Install]
RequiredBy=b.service
```

And then:

```
systemctl enable a.service
```

Now whenever `b.service` starts -- either via a timer or via `systemctl start` -- your new `a.service` will start first.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, i've tryed this solution before but it didn't work because i run the command `systemctl daemon-reload` instead of `systemctl enable b.service` after modified of the service file

Answer (score 0):

The `Before` directive is only used during startup. It's only used for to determine the orders of the services.

In order to achieve what you need, add the following section to to your `a.service`:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=b.service
```

Then run:

```
systemctl enable a.service
```

This will ensure that when `b.service` is supposed to get started, `a.service` will be started before.